# Instagram API: how to get 1440px?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Since May, Instagram started rolling out 1440p images for select phones and several sites like deskgram.cc already show them.
I've been trying to use their json api (?__a=1) and changing User-Agent for the most popular phones and still only got 1080p.
Does anyone know what User-Agent to use to get the higher res?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide us with the code you already have for accessing their API.

Comment: Right now there's no code, I just call their json info (i.e. https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1) and change user-agent to try to emulate a phone. 
AFAIK, there is no solution for getting 1440px in the official Instagram API.
An example of an account with many photos bigger than 1080:
https://deskgram.co/raqueltavaresofficial/

Comment: Look at how [gallery-dl](https://github.com/mikf/gallery-dl) does it. It can download 1440px Instagram images.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>AFAIK, 1440px are only being served in the fvno*.fna.fbcdn.net nodes used by several Eastern European countries. So your only hope is to try to use an anonymous proxy or VPN from that region.</strike>

*Update (June/2020)*: the higher-res photos and stories are available worldwide but (in theory) only inside IG mobile app.
Fortunately there's a way to anyone have access by using a library called "Instagram Private API".